# jQuery add markup dynamically with the product id from the row

Tags: jquery, html

I have my markup is like this. Here you can see I have product id, product name and the last column is the blank one. So in the last column(blank) I want to add a markup like this
`<a class="remove-product" data-id="5" href=""><i class="icon-remove"></i></a>` in jquery
Here is the markup you can see I have the data-id. I want that this data-id will be assigned from the project id value for each row. Like for the 1st row the data-id should be 5 as in the 1st row product id is 5, for the 2nd row this should be 7 as the product id for the 2nd row is 7 and so on. So can someone tell me how to add this?

```
<table class="table products">
    <thead>
        <tr class="nodrag nodrop">
            <th class="">
                <span class="title_box">Product ID</span>
            </th>
            <th class="">
                <span class="title_box">Product Name</span>
            </th>
            <th class="">
                <span class="title_box">Action</span>
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="odd">
            <td class="pointer">5</td>
            <td class="pointer">Summer Dress</td>
            <td class="pointer"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even">
            <td class="pointer">7</td>
            <td class="pointer">Printed Dress</td>
            <td class="pointer"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="odd">
            <td class="pointer">8</td>
            <td class="pointer">Printed Summer Dress</td>
            <td class="pointer"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="even">
            <td class="pointer">9</td>
            <td class="pointer">TShirt</td>
            <td class="pointer"></td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
    </table>
```

Sorry but I can change the markup. It is coming from other source.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("table.products tbody tr").each(function(){
    var ID = $(this).find("td:first-child").html();
    var link = '<a class="remove-product" data-id="'+ID+'" href="#"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a>';
     $(this).find("td:nth-child(3)").html(link);
});});
```

Fiddle URL: http://jsfiddle.net/SachinDhir/df54dkjx/1/

Answer (score 0):

how about [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/r8j27Ljo/)

```
$('.products tbody tr').each(function(index,elem){
    var $elem = $(elem);
    $elem.find('td').last().append('<a class="remove-product" data-id="'+$elem.find('td').first().html()+'" href=""><i class="icon-remove"></i>Remove</a>');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work. Check out the **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6uth2py5/1/)**

```
$('.products tbody tr').each(function() {
    var val = $(this).find('td:first-child').html();
    $(this).find('td:last-child').append('<a class="remove-product" data-id="'+val+'" href=""><i class="icon-remove"></i>Delete</a>')    
});
```

Here we fetch the data-id for the last `td` element from the value of the first `td` element as required and append the value to the last one

Answer (score -1):

The following code will add defined html in last column.

```
$(document).ready(function () {   
$('.products tbody tr').append('<a class="remove-product" data-id="5" href=""><i class="icon-remove"></i>Delete</a>');});
```

Here is jsfiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/rasingh3984/Lzyhk24x/

Comment: You are hard coding the value of `data-id` which is not right.